# Laravel Echo not receiving Pusher event in Laravel 8- vujs "^2.5.17" version

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

**I have recived the event details in pusher debug console but I am not able to get any response in my browser (no console log).Plese help me sir/ma'am**

**I write Echo in app.js**

```
created () {
    window.Echo.channel('privateChat')
        .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
}
```

**Event broadCasting function**

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $message = new Message();
    $message->user_id = $user->id;
    $message->message = $request->message;
    $message->friend_id = $request->friendID;
    $message->my_id = $user->id;
    $message->save();
    // broadcast(new MessageSent($user, $message))->toOthers();
    event(new ChatEvent($request->friendID));
    return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
}
```

**BroadCast service provider**

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function boot()
{
Broadcast::routes();
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']]);
require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
}
```

**Events in chatEvent.php**

```
class ChatEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $friendID;

public function __construct($friendID)
{
    return $this->friendID = $friendID;
}
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('privateChat');
}
}
```

**routes in channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('privateChat', function () {
return Auth::check();
});
```

**Laravel-Echo config in aap/js/bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
        },
    },
});
```

**Versions**

```
"laravel-echo": "^1.10.0",
"laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
"popper.js": "^1.12",
"pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"laravel": "8",
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: please post your Laravel Echo config.

Comment: ```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Uzair Riaz sir, sorry sir i am unable to post it in a proper format , so i put config file into my question part , please check

Comment: could you try returning `true` instead of `Auth::check()` in channels.php, just to check if this is a channel auth issue?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `window.echo.channel()` use `window.echo.private()`.

Also make sure you have set the correct broadcast driver in .env file. If you are using pusher it should be `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` after that do `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I don't know how to ever thank you enough. I just lost 9 hours debugging what was cache's fault. My code was fine all along, I just had to clear cache